# setContentView(R.layout.webview) throwing ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-layout, metaio

The `setContentView(R.layout.webview)` method is throwing ResourceNotFoundException when am trying to run the sample metaio sample app. I checked the folder structure, I deleted the `R.java` resource file and it got recreated.

The Project Structure : 
[image]

The resource generated file

[image]

The log error

[image]

The webview file is present.. Then why is it throwing the `ResourceNotFoundException` ?
Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes you have to restart everything in order for the errors to magically disappear, try even restarting your PC.

Comment: Did you clean the project already? It sometimes also helps to close eclipse and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Clean Project and Rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, 1) Clean Project and Rebuild as others have specified. 
2) I've seen this before, are you sure that webview in the screenshot is a layout and not an id?

Answer (score 0):

guys i did all the possible stuff

- clean
- refresh
- build again
- deleted R.java file
- restart eclipse | restart windows
- different version of eclipse

Nothing helped but when in the end i tried it on my desktop with Windows 7, it worked without any problems..

Earlier I was running on Windows 8.. Although I doubt that it was the windows problem but in the end am glad it worked.